# WMI ExecNotificationQuery using golang

Tags: go, wmi, wql

I am using [this go WMI package](https://github.com/bi-zone/wmi) to monitor windows processes which are starting and stopping. I have see the [example](https://github.com/bi-zone/wmi/blob/master/examples/events/main.go) an implemented my own methods using `Win32_Process` and `__InstanceCreationEvent` and `__InstanceDeletionEvent`.

Here is the sample for `__InstanceDeletionEvent`:

```
func (e *Events) deleteProcessNotify() error {

    query := `
              SELECT * FROM  __InstanceDeletionEvent
              WITHIN 1
              WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'
    `

    events := make(chan event)

    q, err := wmi.NewNotificationQuery(events, query)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(
            fmt.Sprintf("Failed to create NotificationQuery; %s", err),
        )
    }

    go func() {
        e.errCh <- q.StartNotifications()
    }()

    log.Println("Listening for events", CLS)
    for {
        select {
        case ev := <-events:
            fmt.Printf("[%v] Name: %v, Pid: %v, PPid: %v\n",
                CLS,
                ev.Instance.Caption, ev.Instance.ProcessId, ev.Instance.ParentProcessId,
            )
        case sig := <-e.sigs:
            log.Printf("Got system signal %s; stopping", sig)
            q.Stop()
            return nil
        case err := <-e.errCh: // Query will never stop here w/o error.
            log.Printf("[ERR] Got StartNotifications error; %s", err)
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Above code works find but `Win32_Process` does not support **ExitStatus** and I decided to use `Win32_ProcessTrace`. But when I am closing applications, nothing is happening under `case ev := <-events:` this case.

Here is the method for `Win32_ProcessTrace`:

```
func (e *Events) deleteProcessNotify__Trace() error {

    query := `
              SELECT * FROM  __InstanceDeletionEvent
              WITHIN 1
              WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_ProcessTrace'
    `

    events := make(chan event)

    q, err := wmi.NewNotificationQuery(events, query)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(
            fmt.Sprintf("Failed to create NotificationQuery; %s", err),
        )
    }

    go func() {
        e.errCh <- q.StartNotifications()
    }()

    log.Println("Listening for events", CLS)
    for {
        select {
        case ev := <-events:

            // THIS EVENT IS NEVER OCCURRED AND 
            // I REALLY DONT KNOW WHY!!!
            //

            fmt.Println(ev)

            //
            //
            //


        case sig := <-e.sigs:
            log.Printf("Got system signal %s; stopping", sig)
            q.Stop()
            return nil
        case err := <-e.errCh: // Query will never stop here w/o error.
            log.Printf("[ERR] Got StartNotifications error; %s", err)
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing it wrong; try to adapt the example from [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstoptrace) instead.

Comment: I've already read the mentioned document, but had no luck to fix the issue. Do you note any wrong steps in my code. because from my point of view, I see things are correct.

Comment: I can only guess, but: 1) `Win32_ProcessTrace` is explicitly listed as a base class for other tracing classes; I hence have no idea whether you can at all use it directly; 2) Nowhere can I find a clear statement that the `__InstanceDeletionEvent` event gets triggered on that class—note that this event means "something" leaves the "scope"/"namespace" represented by a class; I would argue that a process termination is a regular tracing event—do you feel the difference?

Comment: … I mean, `Win32_Process` is a class which lists all currently available processes; when a process terminates, it's sensible an event is generated for it "leaving" that list. As opposed to this, a trace is just a stream of events—any process-related events of process starts or stops—if you'll take more specific instances of tracing classes.

Comment: @kostix, Thank you for the provided information. I was implemented the second method totally wrong. As I read your additional comments. I found that I should write my query as `query := "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"` instead of `SELECT * FROM  __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_ProcessTrace'`.

Comment: So, have you managed to get proper events using the `Win32_ProcessTrace`?

Comment: No, I have managed it to get the proper event from `Win32_ProcessStopTrace`.